# Is there any Way to Password Protect any Particular WordPress Category?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm Trying to password protect some specific Category on WP so that Category/Menu can be accessible to the users with the Password.

I Want to password protect [Interview](http://programmingquestion.com/category/interview/) category.

I would like to do something like this- 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BfWS.png)

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/access-category-password/ tried this plugin?

Comment: @naththedeveloper i want to this for the whole Page ..if i use this plugin then users have to enter the Password for every post! This way they've to enter password for a lot of posts and on a single Page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with login details.first check user is login or not.if user login than display category otherwise display message login required...

Comment: Hi Rajnik thanks for your reply but i don't want to let them login It would be like a site where you don't need to register but to access some part of the site you just need to have a code which i'll give them after Subscribing to my Newsletter